# Jquery validation library

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
remote: {
        url: 'ajax_php/admin/checking.php',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            username: function() {
                return $("#username").val();
            }
        }
    }
```

When the ajax fn is trigged, in my fire bug, I could see post values, my console shows url status as 200 then it tutns url into red.

First time, it trigger but from next time, it is not posting values to my PHP.

IS this the way remote is used in jquery validate. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: There's an extra comma at the end of the `url:` line, is that in the real code?

Comment: @Barmar:It was a typo.I have it correctly in my ocde.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use max and min, while using remote.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no issues like that.  Make this a useful answer by showing what you're talking about.